# NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT spellout-ordinal in russian and italian

Tags: php, icu, intl, numberformatter

this code works for english, spanish and german ordninal numbers, but with russian or italian ordninal numbers it doesn't work.

`'ru-RU'`,`'it-IT'` also don't work

I get for example in russian for 2 -> два (this is the cardinal number) , but I want the ordinal number and this would be here 2 -> второй.

I get for example in italian for 2 -> due (this is the cardinal number) , but I want the ordinal number and this would be here 2 -> secondo.

**Update:**

I found a solution with works in french, spain, german and some other languages:

maskuline ordinal numbers: `%spellout-ordinal-maskuline`

feminine ordinal numbers:  `%spellout-ordinal-feminine`

russian and italian version doesn't work and I tried already with -maskuline/-feminine

```
$ru_ordinal = new NumberFormatter('ru', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$ru_ordinal->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%spellout-ordinal");
```

Comment: For me calling `format(42)` result is (in order): "сорок два", "cuarenta y dos" and "quaranta ­due". Is this the expected output? Make sure you have intl installed.

Comment: the ordinal number for 42 called "сорок второй", in spainish "cuadragésimo segundo", in italian "quarantaduesimo

Comment: yeah i tested it `$ru_ordinal->format(42);` returns **сорок два** instead of **сорок второй**. this is weird

Comment: @user1978142 It all works fine for me! I think you don't want the number as ordinal number alone, but the number as date like: `it's the second day` and you don't want: `It's the two day` right?

Comment: @Rizier123 How does it show the ordinal number? I am searching for a solution only for the ordinal numbers for russian and italian.

Comment: @Grischa Do you want the ordinal number like: `it's the second day` in all languages or do you want it like `it's the two day` ? Like you don't want to use the number translated alone, you wanted it with a date or something like that?

Comment: @Rizier123 I want the ordinal number in russian and italian, in your example it would be `second`. I want to translate the number  alone!

Comment: @Grischa Yes that means e.g. you DON't want 2 -> два you want: 2 -> `второй` right? and right now you get the first one?

Comment: @Rizier123 Exactly an in italian I get 2 -> `due` instead of 2 -> `secondo`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68568/discussion-between-grischa-and-rizier123).

Comment: @Grischa No i just wanted to make it clear what you want, now i got it :D I think you should add that to you question and show what exactly you want!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

NumberFormatter is using ICU formatting.

As you can check here: http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/extensibility/config-extend/localizing/ICU-numbering-dates/ICU-numbering.html

... **Russian (ru)** has following formatting available:

- spellout-cardinal-feminine (scf)
- spellout-cardinal-masculine (scm)
- spellout-cardinal-neuter (scne)
- spellout-numbering (sn)
- spellout-numbering-year (sny)

... and **Italian   (it)**:

- spellout-cardinal-feminine (scf)
- spellout-cardinal-masculine (scm)
- spellout-numbering (sn)
- spellout-numbering-year (sny)
- spellout-ordinal-feminine (sof)
- spellout-ordinal-masculine (som)

That is why **you will not be able to set ordinal format for (ru)** and following code:

```
$nFormat = new NumberFormatter('it', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$nFormat->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%spellout-ordinal-feminine");

var_dump($nFormat->format(42));
```

Will print:

```
string 'quaranta­duesima' (length=17)
```

Like you (propably) want.

**EDIT:**

Informations about used formatting with references to ICU: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.create.php

Tested with PHP 5.4.x and ICU version => 51.2; ICU Data version => 51.2.
You can use shell command:

```
$ php -i | grep ICU
```

To check what version of ICU you have.

For latest ICU version you should propably install/update php-intl package: http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

**EDIT 2:**

I have created extension for NumberFormatter (so far with polish ordinals). Feel free to contribute another languages: https://github.com/arius86/number-formatter

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately my hoster only update recently to PHP 5.4 and ICU 4.4.1. I have checked your code on http://phpfiddle.org/ and here I get the cardinal number instead the ordinal number.

Comment: Phpfiddle uses PHP 5.3.29. I tested this on 5.4.12. I added some addtional references. I think that ends the topic and in fact there is no other answer for now so I hope you will mark it as accepted. Best wishes!

Comment: Thanks again, but I already know the addtional references. It also don't work on 5.4.36-1. This PHP version is used on my website.

Comment: Here you go, working example on my server: http://private.arius.pl/test/example.php?number=12 - you can change number like you want. Update your servers locale to have correct values for italian.

Comment: Can you show me the code for example.php like example.phps ? I don't know, if I can change my server locale. I don't use my own server. Does ist also works with `%spellout-ordinal-maskuline` instead of `%spellout-ordinal-feminine` ?

Comment: Basically there is the same code as I pasted in the answer (only echoed and added phpversion() call). I checked most of php fiddles and except one they have the same problem (there is cardinal instead ordinal). So propably this is quite common misconfiguration for hosting services :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68571/discussion-between-grischa-and-arius).

Comment: spellout-ordinal-masculine for russian work great. But wrong on ukrainian, have any idea? ICU: 64.2

Answer (score 2):

Just a Recommendation, I am not sure if this works or have an Apache services open at this point of time as I am at college, but have you tried to put ru-RU for Russia. In PHP I personally put my Language Codes as "en-GB"

http://download1.parallels.com/SiteBuilder/Windows/docs/3.2/en_US/sitebulder-3.2-win-sdk-localization-pack-creation-guide/30801.htm

Here is a List I found on the internet with some to help you.

Comment: Thank you, but I had also tried ru-RU and fr-FR for french, es-ES for spanish, it-IT for italian, it works only english and german.