# PHP 7.1 uses another ICU version?

Tags: php, php-7, numberformatter

The answer for my [question about using NumberFormatter with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282324/numberformatterspellout-spellout-ordinal-in-russian-and-italian) for russian ordinal numbers I had an answer, was ICU wouldn't support spellout for ordinal numbers.

But I found on a Number Format Tester from [Unicode.jsp website](http://st.unicode.org/cldr-apps/numbers.jsp), that their are many expressions for ordinal number spellouts.

Instead of adding a Gender, we have to add a Gender and a (grammatical) case for example: `spellout-ordinal-masculine-accusative`.

Like in other languages their are also the rule `spellout-ordinal-masculine`.

My hosted website uses the old ICU version 4.4.1 so I will get everytime the cardinal result: 'один', but I want to get 'первый'.

I tried it on 3v4l.org and in Output for 7.1@2015-11 I got the correct results.

We had already created an addon for russian and polish ordinal numbers for NumberFormatter [@Github](https://github.com/Lern-Online/number-formatter), but I want to know, why with PHP 7.1 it shows the correct value.

**results from  3v4l.org**

result for [spellout-ordinal-masculine](https://3v4l.org/lgeqS)

result for [spellout-ordinal-masculine-accusative](https://3v4l.org/38CTM)

**code**

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('ru', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
$formatter->setTextAttribute(NumberFormatter::DEFAULT_RULESET, "%spellout-ordinal-masculine");

echo $formatter->format(1);
```

EDIT: I tried many numbers and 21000th is the last one, which is spelled out.